# Add condition to PXSelect

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a condition to a PXSelect defined on the SOShipmentEntry graph. I had read that I can just redefine the PXSelect and it would overwrite the original value with mine, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

I created the graph extension as usual, then defined the PXSelect with the extra "And" I need like this:

```
   public PXSelectJoin<SOShipmentPlan,
                          InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, On<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.planID>>,
                          InnerJoin<SOLine, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>, And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>, And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>,
                          InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.inventoryID>>,
                          LeftJoin<INLotSerClass,
                              On<InventoryItem.FK.LotSerClass>,
                          LeftJoin<INSite,
                              On<SOLine.FK.Site>,
                          LeftJoin<SOShipLine,
                                      On<SOShipLine.origOrderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>,
                                      And<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>,
                                      And<SOShipLine.origLineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>,
                                      And<SOShipLine.origSplitLineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.splitLineNbr>,
                                      And<SOShipLine.confirmed, Equal<boolFalse>,
                                      And<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, NotEqual<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>>>>>>>>>>>,
                          Where<SOShipmentPlan.siteID, Equal<Optional<SOOrderFilter.siteID>>,
                          And<SOShipmentPlan.planDate, LessEqual<Optional<SOOrderFilter.endDate>>,
                          And<SOShipmentPlan.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>,
                          And<SOShipmentPlan.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
                          And<SOLine.operation, Equal<Required<SOLine.operation>>,
                          And<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr, IsNull,
                          And<SOLineExt.usrShipmentHold, NotEqual<True>>
                          >>>>>>> ShipmentScheduleSelect;
```

Edit: After reviewing the code posted by Samvel, I found some additional information online and have created a delegate method below. However, when this runs, I am getting the message that the SiteID is not found, and the Site ID appears to be blank. When I step through the code, PXView seems to contain all of the parameters passed in as expected. It's almost like the parameters are being wiped out. I tried copying the parameters to a new array as well, but that also didn't work. Any ideas?

```
    public IEnumerable shipmentScheduleSelect()
    {
        PXView select = new PXView(Base, true, Base.ShipmentScheduleSelect.View.BqlSelect);

        select.BqlSelect.WhereAnd(typeof(Where<SOLineExt.usrShipmentHold, NotEqual<True>>));

        Int32 totalrow = 0;
        Int32 startrow = PXView.StartRow;
        List<object> result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters,
               PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings,
               PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);
        PXView.StartRow = 0;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can override the data delegate which will be the function with the same name like `shipmentScheduleSelect`

Comment: Then you Samvel. I tried doing that a couple of ways. One I used the [PXOverride] attribute, and I received the error "Method System.Collections.IEnumerable shipmentScheduleSelect() in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph". I then tried without the PXOverride attribute, and I received the message "Field not found: 'PX.Objects.SO.SOShipmentEntry.ShipmentScheduleSelect'". I used created it as "public IEnumerable shipmentScheduleSelect()"

Comment: If you want the restriction to be always active, you could use CacheAttached on the DAC you want to restrict and put the condition in a PXRestrictor attribute.  This restrictor can be conditional, and it is less likely to break with upgrades than to override the entire view.  I recommend only overriding the entire view if you need to add another DAC into the select, which I also would advise to do only with extreme caution.  If you need an example of PXRestrictor, please provide some context of your conditional restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below an example of how you can add the data delegate for this specific case:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        public IEnumerable shipmentScheduleSelect()
        {
            throw new PXException("TEST EXCEPTION");
            /*
            Replace the PXException with the override of the select as you need. Below is just an example how you can do that but make sure to provide all the parameters to the select
            var cmd = new PXSelectJoin<SOShipmentPlan, InnerJoin<SOLineSplit, On<SOLineSplit.planID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.planID>>,
                InnerJoin<SOLine, On<SOLine.orderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>, And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>, And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>>>>,
                InnerJoin<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOShipmentPlan.inventoryID>>,
                LeftJoin<INLotSerClass, On<InventoryItem.FK.LotSerialClass>, LeftJoin<INSite, On<SOLine.FK.Site>,
                LeftJoin<SOShipLine, On<SOShipLine.origOrderType, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderType>,
                    And<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.orderNbr>,
                        And<SOShipLine.origLineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.lineNbr>,
                            And<SOShipLine.origSplitLineNbr, Equal<SOLineSplit.splitLineNbr>,
                                And<SOShipLine.confirmed, Equal<boolFalse>,
                                    And<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, NotEqual<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>>>>>>>>>>>,
                Where<SOShipmentPlan.siteID, Equal<Optional<SOOrderFilter.siteID>>,
                    And<SOShipmentPlan.planDate, LessEqual<Optional<SOOrderFilter.endDate>>,
                        And<SOShipmentPlan.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>,
                            And<SOShipmentPlan.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>,
                                And<SOLine.operation, Equal<Required<SOLine.operation>>,
                                    And<SOShipLine.origOrderNbr, IsNull>>>>>>>(this.Base);
            List<object> pars = new List<object>(){
                siteId,
                endDate,
                orderType,
                orderNbr,
                operation
            };
            bool condition = true;
            if(condition)
            {
                cmd.WhereAnd(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemClassID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>>));
                pars.Add("TEST_ITEM_CLASS");
            }
            return cmd.Select(pars.ToArray());
            */
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Samvel, thank you for the information. I think this has me on the right track. However, now I am getting an error saying SiteID does not exist. I confirmed I am passing it in the array of parameters correctly and the Site ID I am passing does exist. Any ideas why it would not be able to find the site? Is it something to do with the currents in the cache of Base?